# Confusion regarding blocks in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have a bit of confusion regarding blocks.

Say for example I have a block with completion BOOL:

```
-(void) addNewSubGoalToLocalDatabaseAndParse:(CompletionBlock )cb
{
    SubGoal* subGoalToAdd = [SubGoal new];
    subGoalToAdd.name = subGoalName;
    subGoalToAdd.parentGoal = goal;
    Score* scoreToAdd = [Score new];
    scoreToAdd.score = 0;
    scoreToAdd.subgoal = subGoalToAdd;
    [subGoalToAdd pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        [scoreToAdd pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
            if (succeeded) {
                NSLog(@"NEW SUBGOALS AND SCORES ADDED");
                [subGoalToAdd saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    if (succeeded) {
                        [scoreToAdd saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                            if (succeeded) {
                                NSLog(@"NEW SUBGOALS AND SCORES ADDED");
                                cb(true);
                            }
                        }];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    }
}];
}
```

Now here i am sending true to the block when all the operations are completed.Say if i send true to the block after the first succeeded will it exit the whole block or continue to run the code asynchronously?

Comment: That looks pretty complicated.  You should redesign the code to do those 4 things sequentially, in a background thread, then call the completion handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function,that is callBack,not return.You method will return first.Because there is a lot async code in your code
So,if

```
-(void) addNewSubGoalToLocalDatabaseAndParse:(CompletionBlock )cb
{
SubGoal* subGoalToAdd = [SubGoal new];
subGoalToAdd.name = subGoalName;
subGoalToAdd.parentGoal = goal;
Score* scoreToAdd = [Score new];
scoreToAdd.score = 0;
scoreToAdd.subgoal = subGoalToAdd;
[subGoalToAdd pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
if (succeeded) {
    cb(true);
    [scoreToAdd pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"NEW SUBGOALS AND SCORES ADDED");
            [subGoalToAdd saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded) {
                    [scoreToAdd saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                        if (succeeded) {
                            NSLog(@"NEW SUBGOALS AND SCORES ADDED");
                            cb(true);
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
}];
}
```

You will have two callBack.

I test with those code

```
-(void)testFunction:(CALLBACK)callback{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    sleep(2);
    callback(@"1");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        sleep(2);
        callback(@"2");
    });

});
}
```

Then call

```
 [self testFunction:^(NSString *str) {
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}];
```

This will output

```
2015-05-29 15:57:24.945 OCTest[5009:261291] 1
2015-05-29 15:57:26.950 OCTest[5009:261291] 2
```

Comment: Thanks alot man that was some seriously good explanation..This cleared my concept..

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,it will exit the whole block if you  send `cb(true);` in the  first succeeded block.

Comment: No code returns until it reaches the end of its scope or the `return` statement is used (ignoring exceptions).  Why are blocks any different?